# Running .net api inside docker with secure connection does not work

Tags: .net, linux, docker, ssl, https

I am really struggling with this. Before I start, everything works on the unsecure `http` connection. But I want/need a secure `https` connection. So I added

```cs
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

in my `Startup.cs` file in the `Configure` section.

### Local windows machine

On my local (Windows) machine, local host works normally on the `https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html`.

### Server

On my server (Ubuntu 20.04) machine, local host works **almost** as expected. The link `https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html` works but the connection is not secure. Why?

### Docker on server

When running from Docker using the

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
RUN sed -i'.bak' 's/$/ contrib/' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer fontconfig
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MetuljmaniaDatabase.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./MetuljmaniaDatabase.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "MetuljmaniaDatabase.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MetuljmaniaDatabase.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MetuljmaniaDatabase.dll"]
```

and

```sh
docker run --name backend --mount type=bind,source=/home/mjancic/Documents/Data,target=/Data -p 
8082:443 metuljmania/dockerapi
```

I get

```
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

when trying to connect to it from the outside.

### Ehm ...

I don't get it. How do fix this. I don't get what I am doing wrong, this really isn't supposed to be that difficult.

### Expected behaviour

Secure connection via Docker. Or actually, at this point I don't even care if it's docker. I just want a secure connection to my API.

Comment: Usually a browser (like Chrome) will tell you why the connection isn't secure if you click on the padlock in the URL. What does it say?

Comment: @HansKilian It says the certificate is invalid. But I don't see this issue on my windows machine. Is there some specific certificate I should install on Linux and Docker?

Comment: I suggest you to *UNDERSTAND* what an SSL certificate is. Try to read  [this article](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/ssl-certificates-explained/)

Comment: To make SSL connections work, ASP.NET Core generates a custom developer certificate. It also installs the certificate as trusted on Windows. But ASP.NET Core doesn't know how to install the certificate as trusted on Linux yet. See [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/32842) for more details.